# Inappbrowser loadstop event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm trying to login via `twitter` account in my `cordova application` for both `ios` and `android` platforms.
After getting the access token I have to fired the `loadstop event` of the `inappbrowser plugin` to proceed with my login code. The problem is that the loadstop event doesn't work. The login page and the autorisation interface have been shown but the event wasn't fired. 
this is my code:

```
 cb=window.open('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?'+data.text,'_self', 'location=no');
 cb.addEventListener('loadstop', function(loc){alert('stop: ' + loc.url);//Twitter.success(loc);
    });
```

How can I fire this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `'_blank'` instead of `'_self'`, _self load the external page on the cordova webview, that means, your code doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: but using _blank I can't hide the done button on the bottom of the web page.

Comment: On iOS you can use the toolbar=no option, that should remove the bar and the button